Unexpected permissions errors when running dev script on vite based project
Everytime I try to run project based on Vite and running dev script, this happens. I'm only able to solve this by running VsCode with as administrator. Setting the folder to R&W permissions for every user does not work.
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
error: Cannot read directory "../..": Access is denied.
error: Could not resolve "C:\\Users\\Jakub\\Desktop\\bloomwarden\\vite.config.js"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1472:15)
    at C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:945:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1315:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:943:7)
    at C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:970:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:677:12)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\bloomwarden\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:600:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:545:12)


Your user don't have access to this folder. Ideally you should never run VSCode or Node (and especially scripts from npm) as administrator, because it is a security risks. Check permissions for a folder with your project (right click, then properties, then security tab, then select your user). There should be at least "read" and "write" permissions for your user and, probably, execute to run scripts. Try with lowest permissions set first, then add if necessary and you understand implications.
